# Dependency of Algorithms, Data structures on Instruction sets ex: Classical vs Quantum computing

Tags: ds.algorithms, memory

It seems to me that

- All/any algorithm(s) evolve based on what's feasible on a machine. This is captured within its instruction set.
- By Analogy data structures are closely associated with physical layout of memory hierarchy on a machine including addressing schemes

Is there a non-formal(with/without math) description of the above dependencies in the form of a set of programming experiments with different instruction sets, memory hierarchies and how they impact design of data structures and algorithms that follow?

Few links that I got :

- a paper on "Data Structures in Classical and Quantum Computing"
- [Elements of computing systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262640686): Building a modern computer from first principles

(PS: Not thinking of expanding the scope to distributed and/or parallel processing systems)

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I understand your question. You mean if there is a description on a different computational model? If that is the question, then yes there are a number of different models; quantum computing is one of them, but there are others as well. The main reason why these models try to mimic real architectures and system capabilities is that we want to be able to run these algorithms. I guess you could argue about completely hypothetical models, but what would the benefit of those be?

Comment: Thanks @KXK . My question was to seek if there was any programming experiments done for a specific problem ex: quicksort on arrays in classical computing is equivalent to some other algorithm with a different data structure in quantum computing.

Comment: Ok, I am afraid that what you are asking is still not well defined. For starters what is your definition of equivalence in the above context? Moreover, you do know we don't - currently - have quantum computers - of any decent computational power anyway - to run programming experiments on right?